# Variable content width fixed sidebar width layout

Tags: css, layout, width

I've searched around the forums but can't get an exact answer to the question. I want to tweak my blog layout at http://techtites.com/ to make the content area flexible width that adjusts when the browser changes width without pushing the sidebar to the bottom.

It is currently a fixed width layout.

Main styles that I've been playing with are:

```
#wrapper {
width:960px;
margin:0 auto;
}

#content {
padding:25px 0;
}

section {
float:left;
width:660px;
margin-right:20px;
}

aside {
float:left;
width:280px;
}
```

I want to make the *section* width to be dynamic, while retaining the *aside* to sit at the right of the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your styles to this

```
section {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    margin-right: -280px;
}

aside {
    float:left;
    width:280px;
}
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/2e9HM/)

Comment: Morpheus, setting section width to 100% causes the sidebar to go below content and content fills the width of everything

Comment: Use `css calc` then. `section { width: calc(100% - 280px)`. It will not work in IE8 and lower.

Comment: Thanks Morpheus, this works. I've tested this on Firefox and program some compatibility for older browsers and Opera as well.

Answer (score 2):

use positioning. set your #wrapper div to `position: relative;` this will position all child elements of that div relative to *it* rather than the browser window.

now position your aside to the top left of your #wrapper div

```
aside {
    width: 280px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

and finally, give enough padding to the section div so that it can still expand and contract, but it leaves enough room for the aside. You want the padding to equal the width of the aside (in this case 280px).

```
section {
    padding-right: 280px;
}
```

I put up an example of all of this on jsFiddle: [jsfiddle.net/2e9HM/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/2e9HM/6/)

BONUS: if you really want to get fancy, you can set the `max-width` of your #wrapper div so that the page is flexible within that size. If you do this, make sure you set a `min-width` as well (equal to the size of your aside) so that the aside doesn't fall outside of the #wrapper when the window is shrunk down all the way.

Comment: This seems to give the best result. I've not included the top: 0 option, but this seems to move everything to the top of the window. Am  I missing something?

Comment: Hey @AjayD'Souza As long as the only two elements inside your relatively positioned wrapper are <section> and <aside> you should be fine. I forked the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/5fPef/1/

Answer (score 2):

Morphius solution is the best so far  - for an example, see
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBBdgg

```css
.blbx { 
background:blue;
 width: calc(100% - 100px);
  height:50px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  text-align:center;
  
  
   
}

.rdbx { 
background:red;
 display:inline-block;
   height:50px;
   width: 100px;
  vertical-align:top;
 
}

.surround {
 
  width: 100%;
   height:50px;
  
}

.myimg { max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='surround'>
  <div class="blbx" ><img class='myimg' src="http://assets.cdpn.io/assets/logos/codepen-logo.svg">
  </div><div class="rdbx"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would do:

```
section {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    padding-right:250px;
    height:100px;
}

aside {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
section {
    float:left;
    width:660px;
    margin-right:20px;
    height:100px;
}

aside {
    height:100px;
    margin-left: 670px;
}
```

[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nandhakumarsri9/2e9HM/4/)

Comment: Nandhakumar, not sure if this fixes my width issue for the section when I resize the window?